# Simple SMTP server which can redirect all mail to single address?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, mail-forwarding

We're in the process of setting up a continuous-integration server (Hudson running on CentOS5), and some of our unit tests will cause email to be sent. We'd like to configure the server so that all email sent via the local SMTP server is routed to a single (development) email address (rather than a user on the box) so that we can ensure the email structure/content is correct.

Can you suggest a simple SMTP server app we can install and provide a sample config to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for Dan Bernstein's [mini-qmail](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/mini.html), Bruce Guenter's [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org./nullmailer/), or similar.

Comment: nullmailer won't do this, AFAIK --- it will send mail to an upstream server, but won't change the address.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Exchange you can set a transport routing rule so that all mail from a particular address is redirected to a single mailbox. Not a direct answer to your question but you may not need any *other* SMTP server.

MS has a FAQ for your basic case: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132.aspx